# Hive Druid integration: cannot add overlapping segments

Tags: hadoop, hive, druid

I'm having trouble integrating Hive and Druid. I want to insert some data from hive to Druid and I'm always getting this error.

"FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. org.apache.hive.druid.io.druid.java.util.common.UOE: Cannot add overlapping segments [1992-01-01T00:00:00.000Z/1993-01-01T01:00:00.000+01:00 and 1993-01-01T00:00:00.000+01:00/1994-01-01T00:00:00.000+01:00] with the same version [2018-07-08T02:59:03.084+01:00] (state=08S01,code=1)"

I think this occurs because my HDP cluster is using local time and Druid uses UTC. Any idea how can I solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Best Regards,

José Correia

Answer (score 0):

Irrespective of the timezone, In what scenario do you think this can occur where the 2 timestamps are conflicting in the segment ? What is your segment granularity? I think its some issue in the ingestion data.

Now to fix this - You need to set used=false to one of the segment which you think is not correct, based on your segment granularity and data. After that it should work fine.

Ideally druid performs best with UTC timezone, though you can change the timezone, but I would rather recommend against it and have the ingestion data set the date/time accordingly. Though during the query time you can always make query as per any timezone.

Comment: I think this is a problem with Hive Druid integration (druid storage handler). 
I found this issue, but it's only solved in Hive 3.0 https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-19155?attachmentOrder=asc.
My segment granularity is month.

Comment: hmm, looks like that bug is indeed the case with you.